# Команда поиска файлов

Tags: linux, shell

Найти где лежит init.d во всей системе

```
find / -name "init*" -print
```

command not found

```
find . -type f|wc -l
```

Всё прекрасно работает.

Где я ошибся?

Comment: `command not found` или просто ничего не находит (думаю, что просто ничего не находит)

Comment: Да, вы правы, благоданю

Comment: command not found обрезано, там впереди ешё что-то стоит?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы в данном случае воспользовался коммандой [locate](http://www.linfo.org/locate.html):

```
locate init.d
```

`locate` отработает на порядок быстрее, т.к. будет искать по своей внутренней БД

Comment: Если база не обновлялась, то ничего не найдёте.

Answer (score 1):

Если init.d это директория, то

```
find / -type d -iname "init.d"
```

Answer (score 0):

KoVadim прав, команда просто ничего не находит потому что init.d это папка а не файл. Если ввести:

```
find / -name "my*" -print
```

Всё прекрасно работает

Comment: Я что-то разницы команды в вопросе и в ответе не вижу

Comment: Да, исправил ответ

Comment: Если find ничего нен найдёт, то он просто ничего не выдаст на консоль.

Comment: @RoboNoob: что-то вы странное говорите, find по-умолчанию ищет и каталоги и файлы, если не ограничивать его ключом `-type`.